# How do I bundle a .pyd file with PyInstaller?

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller, executable, or-tools

I wish to package my script as an executable so that I can run it on a computer that does not have Python installed.

I am using PyInstaller to create an executable to *my_program.py*.

I am using the OR-Tools (**ortools**) Python package, specifically, I am using the ***ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp*** module.

The import call is made as so in my code:
`from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp`

When I create the executable and run it on my computer, I receive this message :

```
# ortools.linear_solver._pywraplp not found in PYZ
# swig_runtime_data4 not found in PYZ
# extension module 'ortools.linear_solver._pywraplp' loaded from 'C:\\Users\\<My Name>\\<My Path>\\project_files\\dist\\my_program\\ortools\\linear_solver\\_pywraplp.pyd'
# extension module 'ortools.linear_solver._pywraplp' executed from 'C:\\Users\\<My Name>\\<My Path>\\project_files\\dist\\my_program\\ortools\\linear_solver\\_pywraplp.pyd'
import 'ortools.linear_solver._pywraplp' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x000001A71756C640>
```

and when I run it on a Windows Sandbox Machine, I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_program.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "my_other_program.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1042, in _handle_fromlist
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "ortools\linear_solver\pywraplp.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1042, in _handle_fromlist
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 657, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 556, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1101, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywraplp: The specified module could not be found.
```

My understanding (I may be completely wrong) is the executable does not find the *ortools.linear_solver._pywraplp* module and has to use the *_pywraplp.pyd* that is on my local drive. However, when I run it on a sandbox machine, there is no place to get the *_pywraplp.pyd* file and so the program fails.

Here is my spec file for creating the executable:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['my_program.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\<My Name>\\<My Path>\\project_files'],
             binaries=[('C:\\Users\\<My Name>\\<My Path>\\project_files\\ortools\\linear_solver\\_pywraplp.pyd','ortools\\linear_solver\\')],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\<My Name>\\<My Path>\\project_files\\ortools\\linear_solver\\_pywraplp.pyd','ortools\\linear_solver\\')],
             hiddenimports=['ortools.linear_solver.pywraplp','ortools.linear_solver._pywraplp'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [('v', None, 'OPTION')],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='my_program',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True , icon='graph_icon.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='my_program')
```

I think the solution to this issue is packaging the *_pywraplp.pyd* file in the executable but so far I have not had any luck.

Comment: @Stradivari, hmm.. Would the solution be including the Visual Studio Redistributables with the executables? Because the windows sandbox computer I am testing it on does not have the Redistributables installed on them. I will give it a go and update you

Comment: @Stradivari THANK YOU!! IT APPEARS TO HAVE WORKED! I needed to install the x64 redistributable